# permuting two integrations

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Can someone explain to me what he used after he said '**and permuting the two integrations with respect t and x we conclude** ..'

**Lemma** Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ bounded in at least one space direction.
There exists a constant $C>0$ such that, for every function $v \in C^{1}(\bar{\Omega})$ which is zero
on the boundary $\partial \Omega$

$$
\int_{\Omega}|v(x)|^{2} d x \leq C \int_{\Omega}|\nabla v(x)|^{2} d x
$$
**Proof**

### **.....**

$$
\int_{\Omega}|v(x)|^{2} d x \leq(b-a) \int_{\Omega} \int_{a}^{b}\left|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_{1}}\left(t, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{N}\right)\right|^{2} d t d x
$$
and permuting the two integrations with respect to $t$ and $x,$ we conclude
$$
\int_{\Omega}|v(x)|^{2} d x \leq(b-a)^{2} \int_{\Omega}\left|\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_{1}}(x)\right|^{2} d x \leq(b-a)^{2} \int_{\Omega}|\nabla v(x)|^{2} d x
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting $f(t,x_{2},...x_{N})=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{1}}}v(t,x_{2},...x_{N})$ and using Fubini (i.e. "permuting the integrations") in the first step we get $$\int_{\Omega}\int_{a}^{b}f(t,x_{2},...x_{N})dtdx = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{\Omega}f(t,x_{2},...x_{N})dxdt = \int_{a}^{b} ||f||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}dt$$ So we´re  only integrating the constant expression $||f||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}$ over $[a,b]$, which yields the inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I get it.